# magento add custom field to admin users

Tags: php, admin

I need to add country field to admin user creation.I have created that field.But I can't save that attribute value into database.For saving that new attribute I have used following observer event.

```
<admin_user_save_before>
    <observers>
        <marketplace>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>marketplace/observer_product</class>
            <method>adminUserCountrySave</method>
        </marketplace>
    </observers>
</admin_user_save_before>
```

**In Oberver**

```
public function adminUserCountrySave($observer) {
    $currentUserId =  Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('user_id');
    $currentUserCountry =  Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('user_country'); 
    $userData = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($currentUserId);  
    $userData->setUserCountry($currentUserCountry)->save();
}
```

But it is not working, it shows 
**Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65488 bytes) in D:\xampp\htdocs\SVEP3403\lib\Zend\Db\Select.php on line 421.**
Anyone know please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try bellow code in observer

```
public function adminUserCountrySave($observer)
    {
        $user = $observer->getUser();
        $currentUserCountry =  Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('user_country',false);
        $user->setUserCountry($currentUserCountry);
    }
```

Comment: As an explanation to OP, basically you run out of memory because your `save()` call is triggering the `admin_user_save_before` which triggers your observer and results in an infinite loop.

Comment: Yes, I removed that save(), its working fine.Thanks for your help.